# Logging for multiple objects: IOError

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging

I have a class called `Job` which has a logger

```
class MyFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.filename = filename
        super(MyFileHandler, self).__init__(filename)

    def emit(self, record):
        log_text = self.format(record)
        try:
            fh = open(self.filename, "a")
            fh.write("%s\n" % log_text)
            fh.close()
            return True

        except:
            return False

log_formatter = logging.Formatter('br: %(message)s')
class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(self.name)
        log_hdlr = MyFileHandler('/tmp/%s' % name)
        log_hdlr.setFormatter(log_formatter)
        self.logger.addHandler(log_hdlr)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

jobs = []
for i in range(100):
    j = Job(str(i))
    job.append(j)
```

and jobs go off do something and logs via `job.logger.info()`

but when i have multiple jobs i.e. thousands, it's throwing error

```
IOError: [Errno 24]
    Too many open files:
      '/x/prototype_3885946_1608131132/cm/cm_conv/logs/20160827-195925.log'
```

I thought every time I logged something, it would open then close the file as I have overwritten `emit()`

Is there a pattern/ways to have thousands of loggers?

Comment: @martineau yes, obv thats not the whole point but enough to get across the problem im trying to hightlight...

Comment: fyi log_formatter is right above class Job. only thing thats being used for self.log is self.log.file which is just path to the logfile.

Comment: made ONE change.. and it should address your concern @martineau

Comment: That's an improvement. I was wrong about `log_formatter` not being defined—sorry. Anyway I find it strange that you're not getting a `TypeError` exception from the `getLogger()` call, because the `name` argument being passed it isn't a string, but is instead an integer. You can see this in the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/logging/__init__.py#l1025).

Comment: how about now? i str() the integer

Comment: Yes, that's better. Your code seems basically OK to me, but unless you can provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which someone could use to reproduce the problem, I doubt anyone will be able to help you. One thing you could do yourself is keep track of all the files opened at once in the custom `emit()` method. Just add a `filecount` attribute to your `MyFileHandler` class which is incremented when one is opened and decremented following its closure. That way you can see how many are open at once.

Answer (score 0):

Guess your operating system is running out of file handles.

Comment: well thats obvious. my question is how do i close the file handles so that it only open when its being used.... and not leaving it open when its not writing

Answer (score 0):

Fyi, instead of executing `self.logger.info(msg)` directly, i just wrapped it around the following code which opens filehandler and closes it each time im writing to a log..

rewrite `self.logger.info(msg)` to `self.write_to_log(msg)`

where:

```
def write_to_log(self, msg):
    log_hdlr = MyFileHandler('/tmp/%s' % self.name)
    log_hdlr.setFormatter(log_formatter)
    self.logger.addHandler(log_hdlr)
    self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

    self.logger.info(msg)      # <----- actually calling .info() here

    for handler in self.logger.handlers:
        handler.close()
        self.logger.removeHandler(handler)
```